# Pass variable as condition for if statement in php

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I have dynamic condition for if statement that stored as a variable. How to make if statement worked using that variable as as its condition?

I have tried using eval function but it's still didn't work

Here is my code:

```
$a = 2;
$b = 2;
$c = '$a==$b';
$d = eval('return $c;');

if($d === true){
    echo 'yes';
}
else{
    echo 'no';
}
```

It should be return 'yes', but my current code return 'no'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use double quotes instead of single quote

```
<?php
$a = 2;
$b = 2;
$c = "$a==$b";
$d = eval("return $c;");

if($d === true){
    echo 'yes';
}
else{
    echo 'no';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I never thought that using single or double quotes will affect much in eval function.

Comment: Always remember single quote can not understand variable and double quote can understand the variable

Comment: And please check the correct answer tick

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, I have found this solution. So what I need to do is put the eval function inside if condition:

```
<?php
$a = 2;
$b = 2;
$c = '$a==$b';

if(eval("return $c;")){ //must using double quotes
    echo 'yes';
}
else{
    echo 'no';
}
```